# sorting and saving usage data collected by iptables

Tags: iptables, usage

I use iptables based MAC access restriction. I have listed MAC id's of users whom I want to allow access, and drop rest. And when I run `iptables -vL` it shows all MAC id's and their usage: packets transferred, data in bytesh. So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to make it show data usage in mega bytes?
2. Can I sort it so that the MAC id's of heavy users will come at top?
3. And, finally, can I save the data to disk, may be into a database, so that it can add up and survive reboots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer #1

What's your `iptables --version`?

On mine, `iptables -vL` automatically converts the bytes into Kbytes (K suffix) or Mbytes (M suffix).

#### Answer #2

Use `iptables -x` piped to `sort`, e.g. `iptables -xvL $CHAIN | sort -rn -k 2`

#### Answer #3

Pipe the output of the above commands to a script which will do the database insert.

You may want to further filter the output of Answer #2 using `awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]+/'` to remove the column headings, and `awk '$1 > 1000000'` to see only those values larger than 1'000'000 bytes.

---

#### Process output into CSV format

```
iptables -xvnL $CHAIN | awk -v min=$MINIMUM '$1 ~ /[0-9]+/ && $2 >= min {print $2 "," $11}'
```

Or, if you need the CSV column heading:

```
iptables -xvnL $CHAIN | awk -v min=$MINIMUM 'BEGIN {print "Bytes,MAC"} $1 ~ /[0-9]+/ && $2 >= min {print $2 "," $11}'
```

Comment: The version is `1.4.4`.

Comment: Hmmm... same here. `iptables -vL` *should* convert the bytes count. `iptables -xvL`, on the other hand, shows the full byte count.

Comment: I also use `iptables -v -L -n`. On my desktop it shows in mega bytes. I will re-verify if it works on the ubuntu 10.04 based server at the place I work, and will let you know. Here is a solution to my third question which I found out after I asked the question here. http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/305767-bandwidth-monitoring-with-iptables  But here it's very difficult to reuse the data, for e.g., if I want to generate a csv file to find out who consumes how much.

Comment: ahhh... if it's just CSV you need, I can help. see my edit :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will be using `iptables-save -c` to store the stats to disk and `iptables-restore` at boot up. And whenever required I will use your solution to export the data to csv file.

Comment: @pepoluan I tried using csv export commands. Both the commands give ` /[0-9] run away regular expression error`

Comment: @nixnotwin for some strange reason, the `/` following `+` got whacked. Fixed. Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 3):

AWK is your friend. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK